# Change link href depending on drop-down value

Tags: input, hyperlink, href, dropdown, onchange

I have a button witha a href link:

```
<a href="mysite.com/filter">My button</a>
```

Then I have 3 drop-down (select) inputs, lets call them A, B & C
[image]

Depending on what the users choose, I want the link to be changed as this

```
<a href="mysite.com/filter-A-B-C">My button</a>
```

All three drop-downs will be Required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the following snippet useful. Handle the default values for the query params.

```
<select id="a" onchange="changeUrl()">
  <option value="a1">a1</option>
   <option value="a2">a2</option>
</select>

<select id="b" onchange="changeUrl()">
  <option value="b1">b1</option>
   <option value="b2">b2</option>
</select>

<select id="c" onchange="changeUrl()">
  <option value="c1">c1</option>
   <option value="c2">c2</option>
</select>

 <a id="test" href="mysite.com">My button</a>
  <script>
  function changeUrl(){
  let url="mysite.com?a=";
  let a= document.getElementById('a').value;
  url+=a+"&b=";
  let b=document.getElementById('b').value;
  url+=b+"&c=";
  let c=document.getElementById('c').value;
  url+=c;
  document.getElementById('test').href=url;
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It almost did the job. The problem is that this code generates a href with = and ? and & symbols - "a=a1&b=b2&c=c1", which I do not need. The href which I need is just "...a-b-c"

Comment: Changed a little the text after "url += a + " and it worked perfectly!

Thank you very much Sudhakar! Be health